# How can I get SQL Server column definition with parentheses and everything?

Tags: sql-server, types, information-schema

I need a smart way to get the data types out of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in a way that could be used in a CREATE TABLE statement.  The problem is the 'extra' fields that need to be understood, such as NUMERIC`_`PRECISION and NUMERIC`_`SCALE.

Obviously, I can ignore the columns for INTEGER (precision of 10 and scale of 0), but there are other types I would be interested in, such as NUMERIC.  So without writing lots of code to parse the table, any ideas on how to get a sort of field shorthand out of the column definition?

I would like to be able to get something like :
int,
datetime,
money,
numeric**(10,2)**

Answer (score 7):

```
select column_type = data_type + 
    case
        when data_type like '%text' then ''
        when data_type like '%char' and character_maximum_length = -1 then '(max)'
        when character_maximum_length is not null then '(' + convert(varchar(10), character_maximum_length) + ')'
        when data_type = 'numeric' then '(' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_precision, 18)) + ', ' + 
            convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_scale, 0)) + ')'
        else ''
    end
,*
from information_schema.columns
```

Comment: Doesn't handle varbinary(max)...  oh well.

Comment: I have added an [updated version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11234044/880904) of this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an update (ripoff!) of [GalacticCowboy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253374/880904) to fix some issues and update for all (I think) SQL Server 2008R2 datatypes:

```
select data_type + 
    case
        when data_type like '%text' or data_type in ('image', 'sql_variant' ,'xml')
            then ''
        when data_type in ('float')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(numeric_precision, 18) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when data_type in ('datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'time')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(datetime_precision, 7) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when data_type in ('decimal', 'numeric')
            then '(' + cast(coalesce(numeric_precision, 18) as varchar(11)) + ',' + cast(coalesce(numeric_scale, 0) as varchar(11)) + ')'
        when (data_type like '%binary' or data_type like '%char') and character_maximum_length = -1
            then '(max)'
        when character_maximum_length is not null
            then '(' + cast(character_maximum_length as varchar(11)) + ')'
        else ''
    end as CONDENSED_TYPE
    , *
from information_schema.columns
order by table_schema, table_name, ordinal_position
```

Comment: Not all of the new datatypes - what about the new date/time types? `time`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset` can all take a fractional seconds precision, found in the DATETIME_PRECISION column.

Comment: @MattW good catch, I've updated the script to include datetime_precision on those as well. Perhaps I'll work on adding all types in SQL Server 2016, too.

Answer (score 1):

SMO Scripting should take care of the script generations. I believe that this is what MS uses in SQL Management Studio for script generations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx

@YourComment - `I need a smart way to get the data types out of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in a way that could be used in a CREATE TABLE statement`

This is what you asked for. Short of that, you will have to parse the info schema view results.

Comment: I don't realy want a script for the whole table.  I am trying to get resolvable datatypes in include in generated XQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you're using smo you can get both precision and scale by accessing the Properties colletion of the [Column Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.column_properties.aspx)

Column.Property["NumericScale"].Value

Column.Property["NumericPrecision"].Value

Comment: Thanks for the response. FYI, the syntax uses "Properties" rather than "Property". For example: Column.Properties["NumericScale"].Value