# SQL Server datetime literal - Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server

Am sure I'm missing something obvious here, but how do I pass a datetime string literal to SQL server?

For instance:

```
select * 
from [dbo].temp_rk_table 
where tx_from <= '2015-10-01T06:37:16'  
  and '2015-10-01T06:37:16' < tx_to
```

gives:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Also:

```
select * 
from [dbo].temp_rk_table 
where tx_from <= convert(datetime,'2015-10-01T06:37:16')
  and convert(datetime,'2015-10-01T06:37:16' ) < tx_to
```

gives:

> GetNextRows failed. : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression
>   to data type datetime.

??

Comment: What is the datatype of `tx_from` and `tx_to`? Do you store it as float [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66668/2/0)?

Comment: I don't have any problem converting those strings to `datetime`. Does this line give you any error?
`select cast('2015-10-01T06:37:16' as datetime), convert(datetime,'2015-10-01T06:37:16')`

Comment: @Andrew most likely tx_from and tx_to are not datetimes.

Comment: Yes, they appear to be float, but anyway I wanted to answer RawFocus' question form the first line and point him in the right direction.

Comment: try convert(datetime,'2015-10-01T06:37:16', 126)

Comment: tx_from and tx_to were indeed float in the DB!  Doh!  knew it was something obvious.  Thanks, happy to accept this as an answer if you want to provide (perhaps others will make the same mistake).

Comment: @RawFocus It is perfectly normal to write your own answer and accept that, in lieu of another answer. That way your question is marked as answered at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So (as per the comments) I was indeed missing something obvious!  The TX_FROM and TX_TO variables were defined as FLOAT and hence would not accept my converted datetime strings.

Be sure your datetimes are indeed defined as datetimes.  The query below may help ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/how-can-i-get-sql-server-column-definition-with-parentheses-and-everything)):

```
select data_type + 
    case
        when data_type like '%text' or data_type like 'image' or data_type like 'sql_variant' or data_type like 'xml'
            then ''
        when data_type = 'float'
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_precision, 18)) + ')'
        when data_type = 'numeric' or data_type = 'decimal'
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_precision, 18)) + ',' + convert(varchar(10), isnull(numeric_scale, 0)) + ')'
        when (data_type like '%char' or data_type like '%binary') and character_maximum_length = -1
            then '(max)'
        when character_maximum_length is not null
            then '(' + convert(varchar(10), character_maximum_length) + ')'
        else ''
    end as CONDENSED_TYPE
    , *
from information_schema.columns
```